# Triangulation induces regular CW complex structure

Tags: general-topology, algebraic-topology

If a topological set is triangulable, dose the triangulation map gives it the regular CW complex structure? From definitions, I see it seems to be, but I am not that sure, for may exist some strange examples.

Really, thanks for any help

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you are right. You can see it as a consequence of Proposition 5.33 in Lee's book:

> Introduction to Topological Manifolds, 2nd ed. Grad. Texts in Math.,
>   Springer, 2011.

I quote the proposition:

> If $\mathcal{K}$ is a Euclidean simplicial complex, then the
>   collection consisting of the interiors of the simplices of
>   $\mathcal{K}$ is a regular CW decomposition of $|\mathcal{K}|$ (the
>   polyhedron associated to $\mathcal{K}$).